# Moved to 64-bit Cygwin/X11 after 4 years, getting xterm & gvim errors

Tags: cygwin, x11

I just upgraded to the current 64-bit Cygwin and X11 from old 32-bit versions from 2015. I'm getting some X-windows errors.  The shortcut that  starts X11 runs the following:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin"
```

My `~/.startxwinrc` is:

```
xrdb -load $HOME/.Xresources
xterm
```

I much prefer this over the default starting of X-windows in the absence of `~/.startxwinrc`, which requires mousing down to the `XDG` icon in the system tray to popup a nested menu tree (especially since I'm always using a touchpad rather than a mouse).

***xterm* error messages**

The above works fine, but if I issue the `xterm` command from an `mintty` terminal or `xterm`, I get the following message when the `x-terminal` appears:

```
xterm: cannot load font "-Misc-Fixed-bold-R-*-*-13-120-75-75-C-120-ISO10646-1"
```

The funny thing is, there is no such font in my `Xresources` file or the system `Xresources` file.

Very old `~/.Xresources`:

```
xterm*font:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1
xterm*font1: -*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-11-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xterm*font2: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-70-iso8859-1
xterm*font3: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso8859-1
xterm*font4: -*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xterm*font5: -b&h-lucidatypewriter-bold-r-normal-sans-14-*-*-*-m-*-*-*
xterm*font6: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso8859-1
xterm*toolBar: false
! XTerm.toolBar: false
xterm*toolBar: false
!xterm*background: DarkBlue
xterm*background: rgb:00/00/66
xterm*foreground: White
```

Grepping the system `Xresources` file(s) yield nothing:

```
grep -i 13-120-75-75-C-120-ISO10646-1 /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm
grep -i 13-120-75-75-C-120-ISO10646-1 /etc/X11/app-defaults/*
```

***gvim* error messages**

In addition to the mysterious `xterm` font problem, I get the following error starting `gvim`:

```
$gvim ~/tmp/tmp.txt
Can't resolve "wglCreateContextAttribsARB"
libGL error: required WGL extension WGL_ARB_multisample is missing
libGL error: required WGL extension WGL_ARB_multisample is missing

** (gvim:2058): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

The initial 3 lines only appear on the first invocation of gvim, while the last line (`gvim WARNING`) appears every time `gvim` is invoked, though with a different 4-digit number each time.  These errors do not occur if I simply run vim.  The errors do show up regardless of whether I have a custom /etc/vimrc or not (my vimrc runs slightly different code depending on whether it is called from vim or gvim).  The closest thing I could find online to the `gvim` error is at [this page](http://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/tag/cygwin/page/2), though it has to do with another app (and the cause is not tracked down).

**Commonalities, and my 2 questions**

The `xterm` font error and the `gvim` errors seem to be independent of whether I rely on default `startxwin` behaviour or on my `~/.startxwinrc`.  Depending on whether I launch xterm or gvim from the command line or the XDG menu, the error messages show up as bash shell command output or in `~/.xsession-errors`.

1. Has anyone else observed this behaviour?
2. Can anyone suggest what else I can do to toubleshoot?

(I am not that familiar with X-11, as I am a a data analyst rather than a software developer.)

**Addendum:** I reinstalled all of the cygwin packages.  The problem remains.

**Addendum:**  Here are the font-like packages that I have installed:

```
$ cygcheck -c | grep -i font

adobe-source-code-pro-fonts         1.017-2             OK
dejavu-fonts                        2.37-1              OK
fontconfig                          2.12.6-1            OK
ghostscript-fonts-other             6.0-1               OK
inconsolata-fonts                   1.010-1             OK
libfontconfig-common                2.12.6-1            OK
libfontconfig1                      2.12.6-1            OK
libfontenc1                         1.1.3-1             OK
libXfont2_2                         2.0.3-1             OK
terminus-fonts                      4.40-1              OK
texlive-collection-fontsextra       20180414-1          OK
texlive-collection-fontsrecommended 20180414-1          OK
urw-base35-fonts                    20170801-5          OK
xfontsel                            1.0.5-1             OK
xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic             7.5-3               OK
xorg-x11-fonts-dpi100               7.5-3               OK
xorg-x11-fonts-dpi75                7.5-3               OK
xorg-x11-fonts-ethiopic             7.5-3               OK
xorg-x11-fonts-misc                 7.5-3               OK
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1                7.5-3               OK
```

The six packages starting with "xorg-x11-fonts-" are the only six shown by the Cygwin setup executable.

Comment: There are a few x11 font packages. You can find them in the setup app. They all begin with `xorg-x11-fonts`. Do you have these installed?

Comment: All six of them.  I updated the original posting of the question to capture this.